Disable Image caption on Tika Server
OCR capabilities from the Tika Server include Image Caption descriptions as part of extracting  content. Whenever an MS Office file is sent to Tika the response includes the resulting image analysis.
Is there any way to disable this? The Docker image I am running is: apache/tika:2.9.2.0-full
The command to invoke the server is
curl -v -F upload=@"F:\Docs\Test.docx" http://localhost:9998/tika/form -H "Accept: text/plain"
The response is:
*   Trying 192.168.100.100:9998...
* Connected to localhost (192.168.100.100) port 9998
> POST /tika/form HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9998
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: text/plain
> Content-Length: 557140
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------f32rl89BvfCasdtZzuVjKlU
>
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 22 Apr 2024 13:58:57 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Jetty(9.4.54.v20240208)
<
Regular content extracted from doc

Regular content extracted from doc with a different format.


[image: A screenshot of a computer

Description automatically generated]

[image: A close up of a person's face

Description automatically generated]

This is more extracted text

[image: ]
image1.png


* Connection #0 to host localhost:9998 left intact

Note how is added: [image: A screenshot of a computer Description automatically generated]
The OCR within the images must happen but not the image captions.
I have tried to find a solution in the documentation but it does not mention any.
I would appreciate any help.
